# Firebase analytics and crashlytics data on php website

Tags: php, firebase, crashlytics, google-analytics-firebase, firebase-remote-config

Iam using firebase to store all the crashes and analytics comming from Android and iOS devices this part is done and iam able to monitor all the events on the firebase console.

Now we have a php admin portal (website) and we wanted to show all the crashes and events data on the website instead of the going to firebase console everytime .

Is there any api that i could use to pull crashlytics or analytics data. I have gone through various articles saying to use bigquery but iam not sure how to implement it. I have tried php firebase admin SDK(kriat) but that does not seem to have any api to pull data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Firebaser here - there is not an API that you can connect to that will allow you to pull crash data from the Firebase console or backend. BigQuery is the route you should take to export data from the Firebase console for Crashlytics and Analytics and do further work on it.

Here are some handy links:

- [Exporting Crashlytics data to BigQuery](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/exporting-crashlytics-data-to-bigquery.html)
- [Linking Firebase to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765#working_with_firebase_crashlytics_data_in_bigquery)
- [BigQuery export schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9036484)